# Dump postgres data with indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, vacuum

I've got a Postgres 9.0 database which frequently I took data dumps of it.

This database has a lot of indexes and everytime I restore a dump postgres starts background task *vacuum cleaner* (is that right?). That task consumes much processing time and memory to recreate indexes of the restored dump.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to dump the database data and the indexes of that database?
2. If there is a way, will worth the effort (I meant dumping the data with the indexes will perform better than vacuum cleaner)?
3. Oracle has some the "data pump" command a faster way to imp and exp. Does postgres have something similar?

Thanks in advance,
Andre

Comment: Good question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you use pg_dump, there's no way to preserve the index data -- the index must be rebuilt after importing.  You could simply tar up your whole postgres data directory instead of doing a pg_dump however.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll try that perhaps it will be the best option for me. My only concern is about differences among different minor postgres versions and OSes.

Comment: @FrankFarmer, will tarring the whole Data directory, and moving it to a new server, will things "just work"? If old server is on an older CentOS and PG 8.x, while the new database is on a new hardware stack and with PG 9.6?

Answer (score 11):

If you use pg_dump twice, once with --schema-only, and once with --data-only, you can cut the schema-only output in two parts: the first with the bare table definitions and the final part with the constraints and indexes.
Something similar can probably be done with pg_restore.

Comment: This should actually be close to the accepted answer, and PG documentation itself should make this clear. Otherwise the dump and restore is pretty sophomoric in many real world scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

Best Practice is probably to

- restore the schema without indexes
- and possibly without constraints,
- load the data,
- then create the constraints,
- and create the indexes.

If an index exists, a bulk load will make PostgreSQL write to the database and to the index. And a bulk load will make your table statistics useless. But if you load data first, then create the index, the stats are automatically up to date.

We store scripts that create indexes and scripts that create tables in different files under version control. This is why.

In your case, [changing autovacuum settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) might help you. You might also consider disabling autovacuum for some tables or for all tables, but that might be a little extreme.

Comment: FYI, that's pretty much what pg_dump -> pg_restore does.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe: The OP is just dumping data, though. `pg_dump --data-only` doesn't include `CREATE INDEX` statements. A `--rebuild-indexes` option would be handy, though. Maybe I'll work on that.

Comment: The OP doesn't make it clear at all whether or not they're dumping data with --data-only or not.  I guess that's what they meant by "taking data dumps" but who knows for sure eh?  --rebuild-indexes would be pretty handy tho.